How to add multiple SharePoint files to a Specific SharePoint list record via Power Automate
I'm working with SharePoint Online and Power Automate
I already have a SharePoint folder which is storing multiple files from a customer form when customers choose to  upload files. They can upload multiple files at one time, hence the Apply Loop below!
The following Power Automate Script is...

Getting all file uploads provided by the customer.
I'm using the HTTP action to get the URI for each uploaded item
I am saving each item into a SharePoint folder, with the help of Create file.
The image below details out these steps


I now want to add another action to this process that says "add each of these files as links to my SharePoint List where column SubmissionID eq '@{triggerOutputs()?['body/04 - SubID']}'"
Is this possible?
If so will this require me creating "another" Apply to each loop, or can I do all this new logic within my existing Apply to each loop?

I think I figured it out. All I had to do was

create an initial variable outside my loop towards the top
Within then loop, select action step Append to string variable, and apply my Create file string to it. Something like this...



After the Apply loop is finished, I can see all upload files associated to my initial variable, and update my SharePoint record with Update Item action.

